# Falha em estilização WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, telerik

Tenho um problema com referências de um estilo dentro do código.

Tenho uma DLL de diversos componentes estilizados herdados do pacote do Telerik com apenas algumas alterações como cor, tamanho, etc...

Dentro do programa onde desejo usar os componentes, referencio a dll com o namespace e consigo trazer e usar o componente que quero e apenas alguns vêm com as alterações que escolhi, outros eu consigo usar o componente mas com a padronização básica do Telerik, sem as alterações de estilo que fiz.

O que poderia estar dando errado? Seguem os códigos que estão dando certo:

As alterações feitas no padrão telerik

```
<ResourceDictionary
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:System="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
xmlns:telerik="http://schemas.telerik.com/2008/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:gi="clr-namespace:GI_ComponentesWPF">

<ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="/GI_ComponentesWPF;component/Themes/GIBase.xaml"/>
</ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

<!--a brush that represents the outer border color of the button, when it is in Normal state.-->
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ControlOuterBorder_Normal" Color="#FFb9b9b9"/>

<!--a brush that represents the background color of the button, when it is in Normal state.-->
<LinearGradientBrush x:Key="ControlBackground_Normal" EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
    <GradientStop Color="#FFFFC8C8" Offset="0"/>
    <GradientStop Color="#FFFF6464" Offset="0.333"/>
    <GradientStop Color="#FFFF1432" Offset="1"/>
    <GradientStop Color="#FFFF9696" Offset="0.171"/>
</LinearGradientBrush>

<!--a brush that represents the foreground color of the button, when it is in Normal state.-->
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ControlForeground_Normal " Color="Black"/>


<!--a brush that represents the background color of the button, when the mouse is over it.-->
<LinearGradientBrush x:Key="ControlBackground_MouseOver" EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
    <GradientStop Color="#FFDCC8C8" Offset="0"/>
    <GradientStop Color="#FFDC6464" Offset="0.333"/>
    <GradientStop Color="#FFC81428" Offset="1"/>
    <GradientStop Color="#FFDC9696" Offset="0.171"/>
</LinearGradientBrush>


<!--a brush that represents the inner border color of the button, when the mouse is over it.-->
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ControlInnerBorder_MouseOver" Color="Transparent"/>

<!--a brush that represents the outer border color of the button, when it is pressed.-->
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ControlOuterBorder_Pressed" Color="#ffcdcdcd"/>

<!--a brush that represents the background color of the button, when it is pressed.-->
<LinearGradientBrush x:Key="ControlBackground_Pressed" EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
    <GradientStop Color="#FFBE6E6E" Offset="0"/>
    <GradientStop Color="#FFBE5A5A" Offset="0.333"/>
    <GradientStop Color="#FF960A1E" Offset="1"/>
    <GradientStop Color="#FFBE6E6E" Offset="0.171"/>
</LinearGradientBrush>

<!--a brush that represents the inner border color of the button, when it is pressed.-->
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ControlInnerBorder_Pressed" Color="Transparent"/>


<Style x:Key="RadButtonStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type gi:GIBotaoComumTeste}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Button}}">
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#FF848484"/>
    <Setter Property="Background">
        <Setter.Value>
            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                <GradientStop Color="#FFFFC8C8" Offset="0"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#FFFF6464" Offset="0.333"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#FFFF1432" Offset="1"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#FFFF9696" Offset="0.171"/>
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FF000000"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="3"/>
    <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="1"/>
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="30" />
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="60" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type gi:GIBotaoComumTeste}">
                <Grid SnapsToDevicePixels="True" Margin="0,0,-185.167,-164.584">
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="OuterMouseOverBorder">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="CommonStatesWrapper"/>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="OuterMouseOverBorder">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="OuterMouseOverBorder">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                                    <GradientStop Color="#FF282828"/>
                                                    <GradientStop Color="#FF5F5F5F" Offset="1"/>
                                                </LinearGradientBrush>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="ControlBackground_MouseOver">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                                    <GradientStop Color="#FFBE6E6E" Offset="0"/>
                                                    <GradientStop Color="#FFBE5A5A" Offset="0.333"/>
                                                    <GradientStop Color="#FF960A1E" Offset="1"/>
                                                    <GradientStop Color="#FFBE6E6E" Offset="0.171"/>
                                                </LinearGradientBrush>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="InnerMouseOverBorder">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                                    <GradientStop Color="#FF3C3232"/>
                                                    <GradientStop Color="#FF6E6464" Offset="0.126"/>
                                                </LinearGradientBrush>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="disabledBorder">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="0.5" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="Content"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="BackgroundVisibility">
                            <VisualState x:Name="BackgroundIsHidden">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="OuterBorder"/>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="disabledBorder"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="BackgroundIsVisible"/>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStatesGroup">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Unfocused">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="FocusVisual">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.15">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                <Visibility>Collapsed</Visibility>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="FocusVisual">
                                        <LinearDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.15" Value="0"/>
                                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Focused">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="FocusVisual">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="FocusVisual"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <Border x:Name="OuterBorder" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" CornerRadius="{TemplateBinding CornerRadius}">
                        <Border x:Name="InnerBorder" BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" CornerRadius="{TemplateBinding InnerCornerRadius}"/>
                    </Border>
                    <Border x:Name="OuterMouseOverBorder" BorderBrush="#FFFFC92B" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" CornerRadius="{TemplateBinding CornerRadius}" Visibility="Collapsed">
                        <Border x:Name="InnerMouseOverBorder" BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" CornerRadius="{TemplateBinding InnerCornerRadius}">
                            <Border.Background>
                                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                    <GradientStop Color="#FFDCC8C8" Offset="0"/>
                                    <GradientStop Color="#FFDC6464" Offset="0.333"/>
                                    <GradientStop Color="#FFC81428" Offset="1"/>
                                    <GradientStop Color="#FFDC9696" Offset="0.171"/>
                                </LinearGradientBrush>
                            </Border.Background>
                        </Border>
                    </Border>
                    <Border x:Name="disabledBorder" BorderBrush="Transparent" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="#FFE0E0E0" CornerRadius="{TemplateBinding CornerRadius}" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="Content" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" ContentStringFormat="{TemplateBinding ContentStringFormat}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                    <Border x:Name="CommonStatesWrapper">
                        <Border x:Name="FocusVisual" BorderBrush="#FFFFC92B" BorderThickness="1" Background="Transparent" CornerRadius="{TemplateBinding CornerRadius}" Opacity="0" Visibility="Collapsed">
                            <Border x:Name="FocusInnerVisual" BorderBrush="Transparent" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="{TemplateBinding InnerCornerRadius}"/>
                        </Border>
                    </Border>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```